# Как работает этот код? Python, iter, next

Tags: python, next

Такой код:

```
data = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]
odds = iter(sorted(el for el in data if el % 2))

print([next(odds) if el % 2 else el for el in data])
```

Он сортирует нечетные числа в списке, оставляя на месте четные.

Я посмотрел видео и почитал документацию про iter и next. Iter - создает итерируемый объект, next - берет элементы этого объекта и выводит следующий при каждом новом вызове.

А здесь выводятся сразу все объекты. Я бы от такого кода ожидал либо "1", либо "5". Но он выводит всё правильно. Я не понимаю логику того, как это происходит...

Comment: `odds = iter(sorted(el for el in data if el % 2))` - тут получается итератор с отсортированными нечетными элементами. next при каждом вызове вытаскивает из этого итератора следующее значение. Вот тут `[next(odds) if el % 2 else el for el in data]` цикл идет по элементам исходного списка, и если он четный, возвращает его, а если нечетный, то берет очередной элемент из отсортированного итератора нечетных. Так и получается, что четные остаются на своем месте, а нечетные получаются отсортированными (т.к. берутся из отсортированного итератора).

Answer (score 0):

[Итератор](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) - специальный объект. Каждый раз когда вы применяете к нему [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=next#next) он  отдаёт следующее число. Пока они не кончатся:

```
data = [5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]
odds = iter(sorted(el for el in data if el % 2))

print(next(odds))
print(next(odds))
print(next(odds))
print(next(odds))
```

> ```
> $ python show-odds.py
> 1
> 3
> 5
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "show-odds.py", line 7, in <module>
>     print(next(odds))
> StopIteration
> ```